# How to build a look up function with multiple keys in spark

Tags: sql, scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I am new to *spark*, and asked a similar question last week. It compiled but not working. So I really don't know what to do. Here is my problem: I have table A containing 3 columns, like this

```
-----------
A1  A1  A3
-----------
a    b   c
```

and Another Table B like this

```
------------------------------------
B1  B2  B3  B4  B5  B6  B7  B8  B9
------------------------------------
1   a   3   4   5   b   7   8    c
```

My logic is: A1 A2 A3 are my key, and it correspond to B2 B6 B9 in table B. I need to build a look up function that takes A1 A2 A3 as key and returns me B8.

This is what I tried last week:

```
//getting the data in to dataframe
val clsrowRDD = clsfile.map(_.split("\t")).map(p => Row(p(0),p(1),p(2),p(3),p(4),p(5),p(6),p(7),p(8)))
val clsDataFrame = sqlContext.createDataFrame(clsrowRDD, clsschema)

//mapping the three key with the value
val smallRdd = clsDataFrame.rdd.map{row: Row => (mutable.WrappedArray.make[String](Array(row.getString(1), row.getString(5), row.getString(8))), row.getString(7))}

val lookupMap:Map[mutable.WrappedArray[String], String] = smallRdd.collectAsMap()

//build the look up function
def lookup(lookupMap: Map[mutable.WrappedArray[String],String]) =
udf((input: mutable.WrappedArray[String]) => lookupMap.lift(input))

//call the function
val combinedDF  = mstrDataFrame.withColumn("ENTP_CLS_CD",lookup(lookupMap)($"SRC_SYS_CD",$"ORG_ID",$"ORG_CD"))
```

And this code compiles, but doesn't really return me the results I need. I am thinking it's because I am passing in an array as the key and I don't really have array inside my table. But when I tried change the map type as `Map[(String,String,String),String]`, I don't know how you pass it in the function.

Tons of thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to get `B8` value for every matching of `A1` with `B2` and `A2` with `B6` and `A3` with `B9`, then simple `join` and `select` methods should do the trick. **Creating a lookup map would create complexity.**

As you explained you have to dataframes `df1` and `df2` as

```
+---+---+---+
|A1 |A2 |A3 |
+---+---+---+
|a  |b  |c  |
+---+---+---+

+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|B1 |B2 |B3 |B4 |B5 |B6 |B7 |B8 |B9 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|1  |a  |3  |4  |5  |b  |7  |8  |c  |
|1  |a  |3  |4  |5  |b  |7  |8  |e  |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Simple `join` and `select` can be done

```
df1.join(df2, $"A1" === $"B2" && $"A2" === $"B6" && $"A3" === $"B9", "inner").select("B8")
```

which should give you

```
+---+
|B8 |
+---+
|8  |
+---+
```

I hope the answer is helpful

**Updated**

According to what I understood from your question and comments below, you are confused on how to pass `array` to your `lookup` `udf` function. For that you can use [array](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#array(org.apache.spark.sql.Column...)) function. I have modified some parts of your almost perfect code to make it work

```
//mapping the three key with the value
val smallRdd = clsDataFrame.rdd
  .map{row: Row => (mutable.WrappedArray.make[String](Array(row.getString(1), row.getString(5), row.getString(8))), row.getString(7))}

val lookupMap: collection.Map[mutable.WrappedArray[String], String] = smallRdd.collectAsMap()

//build the look up function
def lookup(lookupMap: collection.Map[mutable.WrappedArray[String],String]) =
udf((input: mutable.WrappedArray[String]) => lookupMap.lift(input))

//call the function
val combinedDF  = mstrDataFrame.withColumn("ENTP_CLS_CD",lookup(lookupMap)(array($"SRC_SYS_CD",$"ORG_ID",$"ORG_CD")))
```

You should have

```
+----------+------+------+-----------+
|SRC_SYS_CD|ORG_ID|ORG_CD|ENTP_CLS_CD|
+----------+------+------+-----------+
|a         |b     |c     |8          |
+----------+------+------+-----------+
```

Comment: you prefer lookupMap rather than join ? :)

Comment: no I would rather use join it's just my requirement is not using join...

Comment: so did my answer helped?

Comment: But you just said you would use joins, didn't you?

Comment: It's more like they've already done it with joins, and wanted me explore how to do with lookup map

Comment: you want your final output as a dataframe ?

Comment: I want my final output to be an Array[Arrays]. Not dataframe, not RDD, just array

Comment: If you have `(1, "a", 3, 4, 5, "b", 7, "8", "c"),(1, "a", 3, 4, 5, "b", 7, "9", "c")` as your tableB, what would be your output?

Comment: I have updated my answer with what I have understood. :) hope this time I got it correct.